# Posting data through hyperlinks

Tags: php, post, hyperlink

I want to post ($_GET as well as $_POST) data by clicking on links (enclosed with `<a>`) and not the regular form 'submit' button. preferred language : PHP

I have seen this in a lot of todays websites,
where forms are submitted by clicking on buttons looking like hyperlinks.
so was wondering how it could be done.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This post](http://ajaxian.com/archives/styling-buttons-as-links-allowing-you-to-post-away) on Ajaxian might help. It links to a pretty in depth blog post that shows you how to apply css to buttons so that they look like links.

The advantage here over using a proper link is the "fake link" really **is** a button, so it behaves exactly like a button, only it looks like a link. Spiders won't follow it, screen readers will treat it differently, it's a more "correct" thing to do in terms of launching a http post.

Comment: No worries. This turned out to be quite a hot little question :-)

Comment: might consider voting it up. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Forms are designed to be submitted with buttons. You can use JavaScript to make a link submit it, but this will break when JS is not available. Even if JavaScript is available, using a link will be using a control which won't show up when a screen reader is in "Forms Mode", leaving screen reader users without any obvious way to submit the form.

CSS is a safer alternative (see http://tom.me.uk/scripting/submit.html).

Comment: Even in light of our little fit - your answer still gets my vote ;)

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
<a href='myform.php?name=Bob&surname=Terrier'>Click here</a>
```

That will submit `name` and `surname` as GET variables to the form.

Beware any form that modifies data though, as search engines and spiders will traverse links where they don't traverse forms.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the "GET" method while submitting data via URLs.

Comment: i need to post &_POST data as well

Comment: @OrangeRind: You should then update your original question, there's no mention of "POST" in there.

Comment: @TFM Umm. Word number 4 of the question?

Comment: "I want to post data" was a bit of a giveaway :-)

Comment: Not really. Post can easily be interpreted as "submitting" data, which is what happens even when the "GET" method is used.

Comment: Not according to the question: "I want to post ($_GET as well as $_POST) data"... ;)

Answer (score 2):

As seen from the other answers, you have to use JavaScript if you want to submit user data from a form with a link. That means you exclude anyone with JavaScript turned off, unavailable, or incompatible with your code. On the other hand, you could try to style a button with CSS to make it look like a link.

Answer (score 1):

Beware posting data by clicking on links!
Spiders may follow this links and change data.

You probably want something like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="form.Submit();">submit</a>
```

Comment: As fallbacks for when JS is not available go, "A link to the top of the page (#)" is pretty poor.

Comment: a good spider won't submit a form if it's method is set to "post"

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Javascript to submit the form.

```
<a href='document.myform.submit()'>Submit Button</a>
```

Comment: As URLs go, that is a normal relative URL (but quite an ugly one)

Comment: i don't know Javascript that well as to submit data.
may be you could specify the code for submit()